# Dividing integer HashMap values produces zero

Tags: java, file, arraylist, hashmap, percentage

Edit 2: After going through the suggestions, I have two possible ways calculating this.
1:

```
    public int percent(String token) {
        if(token != "" && token != "\n" && token != " " && map.get(token) != null) {
            double ag = 0;
            
            for (int x : map.values()) {
                ag += x;
            }
            
            int retval = (int) (((double)map.get(token)) / ag); //mapsize only shows number of unique words; change to ALL words
            return retval;
        } else {
            return 404;
        }
    } //*/
```

2:

```
    public int percent(String token) {
        if(token != "" && token != "\n" && token != " " && map.get(token) != null) {
            double ag = 0;
            
            for (int x : map.values()) {
                ag += x;
            }
            
            int retval = (int) (((double)map.get(token)) / wordCount); //mapsize only shows number of unique words; change to ALL words
            return retval;
        } else {
            return 404;
        }
    } //*/
```

The wordCount at the end is a class attribute that I increment by one every time the constructor adds a value.

Old Edit: Okay, so I have fixed the logical problem that Andy pointed out in the comments. The new method I've written is this:

```
    public int percent(String token) {
            if(token != "" && token != "\n" && token != " " && map.get(token) != null) {
                int ag = 0;
            
                for (String x : map.keySet()) {
                    ag += map.get(x);
                }
            
                int retval = map.get(token)/ag;
                return retval;
            } else {
                return 404;
       }
        
    } //*/
```

However, I still get an output of 0 from my test in Driver. I also took the liberty to change the test.txt and its output below.

Original Post:

I'm currently working on a project where I have to take input from a file and use a HashMap to calculate the frequency of each word. There are a few required methods we have to make for our "freqCount" class, and one of them is `public int percent(String token)`, which takes a string and tries to find how much of the original file matches it. I assumed the easiest way to do this would be to divide the already calculated frequency of the string by the size of the HashMap. When I execute, it returns zero every time.

After changing things here and there and getting results, I discovered that the `/` is what causes the value to go to 0. `+`, `-`, and `*` work fine.

From here I assumed it was the integer type that was rounding the decimal to zero, but even after changing the function to a float or double it still prints 0.0.

Driver:

```
package fint;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Driver {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        //---------------CONSTANTS---------------
        final String PERC_STRING = "the"; //set these to whatever you want for testing purposes
        final String COUNT_STRING = "the";
        
        //---------------------------------------
        
        File in = new File("test.txt");
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(in);
        
        ArrayList<String> parsed = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        
        while(scanFile.hasNext()) { 
            parsed.add(scanFile.next().toLowerCase());
        }
        
        for(int i = parsed.size()-1; i>=0; i--) { //prints arraylist backwards
            System.out.println(parsed.get(i));
        } //*/
        
        FreqCount fc = new FreqCount(parsed);
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        //percent() test
        System.out.println("\nTest word '" + PERC_STRING +"' percentage: " + fc.percent(PERC_STRING));
        
        //count() test
        System.out.println("\nCount of '" + COUNT_STRING + "': " + fc.count(COUNT_STRING));
        
        //printMap() test
        System.out.println("\nHashmap: \n");
        fc.printMap();
        
        scanFile.close();

    }
}
```

FreqCount:

```
package fint;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.Math;

public class FreqCount {
    //attributes----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    private HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    
    //constructors--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    FreqCount(List<String> driverList) {
        for (int dLIndex = driverList.size() - 1; dLIndex >= 0; dLIndex--) {
            String key = driverList.get(dLIndex);
            if (map.get(key) == null) {
                map.put(key, 1);
            } else {
                map.put(key, map.get(key) + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    
    /*FreqCount(List<String> driverList, int degree){ //will specify number (degree) of words in a token (" hello world " would one token of degree 2)
        
    } //*/
    
    
    
    //methods (required)---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    public int count(String token) { //returns value of a key
        if(token != "" || token != "\n" || token != " ") {
            return map.get(token);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } //*/
    

//THIS METHOD v v v v v v v v

    public int percent(String token) {
        if(token != "" && token != "\n" && token != " " && map.get(token) != 0) {
            int retval = map.get(token)/map.size(); //problem area
            return retval;
        } else {
            return 404; //404 isn't special, just random code i chose for debug purposes
        }
        
    } //*/



    
    //testing methods (not required)---------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    public void printMap() {
        for (String i : map.keySet()) { //loop ripped straight outta w3schools lol
              System.out.println("key: " + i + " value: " + map.get(i));
        }
    } //*/

}
```

Text input:

```
There were a number of factors that came together to contribute to the adaptive radiation of monkeys and decreased diversity of apes. The first involves the rifting of the African Plate somewhere between 60 and 10 million years ago. These plates split into what are known today as the Nubian plate and the Somali plate. This split happened alongside volcanic activity creating localized and varied environments. The different environments and food sources forced the populations of primates living in each to evolve through natural selection. The rift of the African plate combined with the phenomenon of continental drift caused the continents of Africa and Eurasia to be reconnected over time.
```

Output (percentage test is about midway through):

```
Hashmap: 

key: through value: 1
key: environments value: 1
key: forced value: 1
key: somewhere value: 1
key: years value: 1
key: these value: 1
key: that value: 1
key: number value: 1
key: split value: 2
key: time. value: 1
key: different value: 1
key: between value: 1
key: drift value: 1
key: 10 value: 1
key: africa value: 1
key: primates value: 1
key: plates value: 1
key: natural value: 1
key: in value: 1
key: involves value: 1
key: this value: 1
key: nubian value: 1
key: varied value: 1
key: continents value: 1
key: each value: 1
key: monkeys value: 1
key: as value: 1
key: environments. value: 1
key: million value: 1
key: were value: 1
key: creating value: 1
key: 60 value: 1
key: apes. value: 1
key: populations value: 1
key: continental value: 1
key: be value: 1
key: sources value: 1
key: activity value: 1
key: localized value: 1
key: contribute value: 1
key: plate value: 3
key: phenomenon value: 1
key: into value: 1
key: adaptive value: 1
key: diversity value: 1
key: known value: 1
key: are value: 1
key: and value: 6
key: of value: 8
key: today value: 1
key: came value: 1
key: together value: 1
key: over value: 1
key: somali value: 1
key: a value: 1
key: living value: 1
key: alongside value: 1
key: caused value: 1
key: plate. value: 1
key: decreased value: 1
key: ago. value: 1
key: food value: 1
key: happened value: 1
key: factors value: 1
key: the value: 12
key: rift value: 1
key: with value: 1
key: evolve value: 1
key: what value: 1
key: radiation value: 1
key: african value: 2
key: selection. value: 1
key: there value: 1
key: to value: 4
key: combined value: 1
key: rifting value: 1
key: eurasia value: 1
key: reconnected value: 1
key: volcanic value: 1
key: first value: 1

Test word 'the' percentage: 0

Count of 'the': 12

Adding 'indubidubly': 
Count of 'indubidubly': 1
Adding 4 more...
Count of 'indubidubly': 5
```

Thanks to anyone who took the time to read this!

Comment: Integer types don't "round the decimal to zero", they [truncate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation) any fractional portion of the quotient.  Q: Could you please update your post, and 1) show is the code that's giving you problems (I don't see any division in the code you posted), and 2) give some example values that are result in "0"?  FYI, you'r post has 59 instances of the "/" character - but not a single "division" ;)

Comment: Oh that's my fault sorry, I copied and pasted the wrong code. Should be fixed now. The method that causes me problems is the percentage one in the FreqCount class.

Comment: You're still doing an integer calculation.

Comment: You should also reconsider the equation: you have "# of occurrences of 1 word / total count of unique words" which is different than "# of occurrences of 1 word / total number of words".

Comment: @tgdavies I'm not sure what you mean. I want the function to be of the integer type so it will return a truncated form of the percentage. Edit: Nevermind thanks for your time!

Comment: @Andy Ah I see. Thanks, it makes me feel a lot better that my problem is with my thinking and not my code.

Comment: Well you still have the integer division issue that others are referring to.  I'm questioning what you are computing.

Answer (score 1):

So you posted a lot of code but really your question is on this one line and the use of integer division.

```
int retval = map.get(token)/map.size(); //problem area
```

So before addressing *what* you are computing, as others are saying the line should look like the following.  I've introduced some local variables for clarity:

```
int freqOfToken = map.get(token);

// You'll have to write this method - iterate over HashMap and tally the
// total number words (or maintain it as you are building the Hashmap)
// (This is the `ag` variable/loop which you've added to post.)
int totalWords = getTotalWords();

// this computes a ratio of two integers yielding [0.0 1.0] (assuming the 
// numerator is always <= denominator which it should be in your problem) and
// converts it to a percent [0 100]
int retval = int (((double)freqOfToken / (double)totalWords) * 100);
```

So compute ratio as a double (or float), scale it by 100 and convert to int.

A few ways to accomplish same (like change 'freqOfToken' and 'totalWords' to `double` to remove the casts in equation.

As to the *what* - I interpret your problem as "what percentage of all of the tokens (words) in the file are one specific token".  Whereas, your implementation does not have a lot of sense but is "what percentage of the unique words in the file is the number of occurences of one token."

So you need to change the equation as is done above to use the total number of words as the divisor (something I don't see you having so I added a new method which you'll have to write).

Comment: I posted an update before I refreshed and saw your post. From your response, is getTotalWords(); a built in function for maps?

Comment: No - you have to write it - you need to tally up the total number of words - or keep track of the total as you are building the hashmap.  So `getTotalWords` is the `ag` loop you added to the post - so you've done it.

Comment: Got it. My first instinct is to create an attribute that gets incremented when the constructor adds a value. Would that harm me in any way? Edit: tried and the same thing still happens.

Comment: Not in this case - but if class operations grew more complex (add more data, remove data) then it'd be easier just to count whatever's in the map after the operation.  By the way, it may be clearer if you iterated over the `values` rather than they `keys` with `gets` (in your `percent` loop computing ag).

Comment: Ok, I implemented both a version with an iterative wordCount variable and a better ag. Both continue to print out 0 :(